# Common view in multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone

I am developing an **iPhone** application, where I have a **common header** among all 65 NIBs.

So, I googled for one day then I am asking here.

I know I have to make a Custom UIView, but how do you **add Custom UIView to all UIViewControllers** in your app, with **"all associated IBActions"**

I've tried this,

```
TopViewController *topVC=[[TopViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TopViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:topVC];
```

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Please stop editing this question with minor spelling mistakes & case mistakes.. We are here at stackoverflow.com to solve programming doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom view controller rather than a custom view. I will add the header I wanted in the viewcontroller's view and set all the actions associated with it in the view controller.

All other view controllers would subclass this view controller. This is how "master pages" works in visual studio.